# Ionic 4 CLI config generate for inline template and style

Tags: ionic4

someone knows how to configure ionic to generate components with inline template and style.
For example in Angular this is **"ng g c foo -t -s"** and on Ionic?. But the idea is configure it in angular.json for default

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your idea were in a right way.
Just remove "defaultCollection" in angular.json and you will be okay

```
"cli": {
  "defaultCollection": "@ionic/angular-toolkit"
}
```

It may break build processes, but you always can return it back.
And it is know issue (https://github.com/ionic-team/angular-toolkit/issues/446) that this toolkit does not support inline template/styles

Comment: Hi, please *Do Not* post your code as an image, post is as a text instead. [Here is why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15366635)